# How to center an individual anchor in a div with other elements

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-5

I am attempting to center an anchor on my webpage. It is going well, other than the fact I've been struggling to get an individual link to the middle of the page. Using `text-align: center;` requires the usage of a div which splits the page onto a new line. Using margins and spans and other tricks found online either split the form onto a new line or do nothing.

```css
span.right {
    float: right;
}
```

```html
<form action="login.py" method="post">
  <div class="container">
    <label for="username">
      <b>Username</b>
    </label>
    <input type="text" placeholder="Enter Username" name="uname" required>
    <label for="pword">
      <b>Password</b>
    </label>
    <input type="password" placeholder="Enter password" name="pword" required>
    <button type="submit">Login</button>
    <label>
      <input type="checkbox" checked="checked" name="remember"> Remember me
    </label>
    <a class="link-secondary" href="#">Sign up?</a>
    <span class="right"><a class="link-secondary" href="#">Forgot password?</a></span>
  </div>
</form>
```

This is what the html displays as, as well as where I would like the span to be, with content "sign up?".

[image: form]

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bootstrap's [flex utilities](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.1/utilities/flex/#justify-content) work well for this (on a new wrapping div): `d-flex justify-content-between`

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous">

<form action="login.py" method="post">
  <div class="container">
    <label for="username">
      <b>Username</b>
    </label>

    <input type="text" placeholder="Enter Username" name="uname" required>

    <label for="pword">
      <b>Password</b>
    </label>

    <input type="password" placeholder="Enter password" name="pword" required>

    <button type="submit">Login</button>

    <div class="d-flex justify-content-between">
      <label>
        <input type="checkbox" checked="checked" name="remember"> Remember me
      </label>

      <a class="link-secondary" href="#">Sign up?</a>
      
      <a class="link-secondary" href="#">Forgot password?</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 2):

Or without using Bootstrap, just using `display: flex;` and the value `space-between` for the `justify-content` attribute:

```css
.flex-container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
```

```html
<form action="login.py" method="post">
      <div class="container">
        <label for="username">
          <b>Username</b>
        </label>
        <input type="text" placeholder="Enter Username" name="uname" required />
        <label for="pword">
          <b>Password</b>
        </label>
        <input
          type="password"
          placeholder="Enter password"
          name="pword"
          required
        />
        <button type="submit">Login</button><br />
        <div class="flex-container">
          <label>
            <input type="checkbox" checked="checked" name="remember" /> Remember
            me
          </label>
          <a class="link-secondary" href="#">Sign up?</a>
          <a class="link-secondary" href="#">Forgot password?</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </form>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<form action="login.py" method="post">
    <div class="container">
        <label for="username"><b>Username</b></label>
        <input type="text" placeholder="Enter Username" name="uname" required>
        <label for="pword"><b>Password</b></label>
        <input type="password" placeholder="Enter password" name="pword" required>
        <button type="submit">Login</button>
        
<div class="flexA">
        <div><label><input type="checkbox" checked="checked" name="remember"> Remember me? </label><a class="link-secondary" href="#">Sign up?</a></div>
        <a class="link-secondary" href="#">Forgot password?</a>
</div>
    </div>
</form>
and add css for flexA : 
.flexA {
display: flex;
justfy-context: space-between;
align-items: center;
}
```

Comment: Some explanation would make this answer better. You have text in your poorly formatted code block.  See [answer].

Answer (score 0):

I add flex in your bottom. it will come as you want.

```
<form action="login.py" method="post">
        <div class="container">
<div class="row">
            <label for="username"><b>Username</b></label>
            <input type="text" placeholder="Enter Username" name="uname" required>
            <label for="pword"><b>Password</b></label>
            <input type="password" placeholder="Enter password" name="pword" required>
            <button type="submit">Login</button>
<div class="remember-bottom d-flex column justify-content-between">
            <label><input type="checkbox" checked="checked" name="remember"> Remember me? </label>
            <a class="link-secondary" href="#">Sign up?</a>
            <span class="right"><a class="link-secondary" href="#">Forgot password?</a></span>
</div>
        </div>
</div>
    </form>
```